# Mongoose delete array element in document and save

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an array in my model document.  I would like to delete elements in that array based on a key I provide and then update MongoDB.  Is this possible?

Here's my attempt:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var favorite = new Schema({
    cn: String,
    favorites: Array
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Favorite', favorite, 'favorite');

exports.deleteFavorite = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.callback !== null) {
        res.contentType = 'application/javascript';
    }
    Favorite.find({cn: req.params.name}, function (error, docs) {
        var records = {'records': docs};
        if (error) {
            process.stderr.write(error);
        }
        docs[0]._doc.favorites.remove({uid: req.params.deleteUid});

        Favorite.save(function (error, docs) {
            var records = {'records': docs};
            if (error) {
                process.stderr.write(error);
            }
            res.send(records);

            return next();
        });
    });
};
```

So far it finds the document but the remove nor save works.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You can also do the update directly in MongoDB without having to load the document and modify it using code. Use the `$pull` or `$pullAll` operators to remove the item from the array :

```
Favorite.updateOne({ cn: req.params.name }, {
    $pullAll: {
        favorites: req.params.deleteUid,
    },
});
```

**To remove objects from array then**

```
Favorite.updateOne({ cn: req.params.name }, {
    $pullAll: {
        favorites: [{_id: req.params.deleteUid}],
    },
});
```

(you can also use updateMany for multiple documents)

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/

Comment: I don't get how this is removing an item from the favorites array (the sub array not the document) without any reference to the name favorites

Comment: Also this operation is atomic. Meaning that the document will not have the potential to change between separate find and update operations.

Comment: @Dominic The `favourites` is now added. I can't believe this went unnoticed for more than 6 years

Answer (score 99):

The checked answer does work but officially in MongooseJS latest, you should use **pull**.

```
doc.subdocs.push({ _id: 4815162342 }) // added
doc.subdocs.pull({ _id: 4815162342 }) // removed
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-pull

I was just looking that up too.

**See Daniel's answer for the correct answer. Much better.**

Comment: @LondonRob +1 made a good edit, we should be careful not to use insecure links in general.

Comment: this is what I needed! It's clean and easy to use with ids that are a ref in another model

Comment: This doesn't work when the document gets updated again

Answer (score 16):

Answers above are shown how to remove an array and here is how to pull an object from an array.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

```
db.survey.update( // select your doc in moongo
    { }, // your query, usually match by _id
    { $pull: { results: { $elemMatch: { score: 8 , item: "B" } } } }, // item(s) to match from array you want to pull/remove
    { multi: true } // set this to true if you want to remove multiple elements.
)
```

Comment: Please be careful when using this example, it might not work in some case as mentioned in the doc above `In fact, the following operation will not pull any element from the original collection.`  . Read the doc above for more detail.

Answer (score 8):

Since favorites is an array, you just need to splice it off and save the document.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var favorite = new Schema({
    cn: String,
    favorites: Array
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Favorite', favorite);

exports.deleteFavorite = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.callback !== null) {
        res.contentType = 'application/javascript';
    }
    // Changed to findOne instead of find to get a single document with the favorites.
    Favorite.findOne({cn: req.params.name}, function (error, doc) {
        if (error) {
            res.send(null, 500);
        } else if (doc) {
            var records = {'records': doc};
            // find the delete uid in the favorites array
            var idx = doc.favorites ? doc.favorites.indexOf(req.params.deleteUid) : -1;
            // is it valid?
            if (idx !== -1) {
                // remove it from the array.
                doc.favorites.splice(idx, 1);
                // save the doc
                doc.save(function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        res.send(null, 500);
                    } else {
                        // send the records
                        res.send(records);
                    }
                });
                // stop here, otherwise 404
                return;
            }
        }
        // send 404 not found
        res.send(null, 404);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough response.

Comment: if you try to remove 2 things at the same time, they both might get the array, then change it, and the first change that is saved gets overwriten by the second. I would rather go with sth like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb .

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me and really very helpful.

```
SubCategory.update({ _id: { $in:
        arrOfSubCategory.map(function (obj) {
            return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(obj);
        })
    } },
    {
        $pull: {
            coupon: couponId,
        }
    }, { multi: true }, function (err, numberAffected) {
        if(err) {
            return callback({
                error:err
            })
        }
    })
});
```

I have a model which name is `SubCategory` and I want to remove Coupon from this category Array. I have an array of categories so I have used `arrOfSubCategory`. So I fetch each array of object from this array with map function with the help of `$in` operator.

Answer (score 3):

I used this format for my project and it's worked

```
router.delete('/dashboard/participant/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const participant = await Participant.findByIdAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id });
        // { $pull: { templates: { _id: templateid } } },
        const event = await Event.findOneAndUpdate({ participants: participant._id }, { $pull: { participants: participant._id } }, { new: true });
        res.status(200).json({ request: 'Deleted', participant, event });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json(error)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
keywords = [1,2,3,4];
doc.array.pull(1) //this remove one item from a array
doc.array.pull(...keywords) // this remove multiple items in a array
```

if you want to use `...` you should call `'use strict';` at the top of your js file; :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Favorite.update({ cn: req.params.name }, { "$pull": { "favorites": { "_id": favoriteId } }}, { safe: true, multi:true }, function(err, obj) {
    //do something smart
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Is pretty simple to read if you read the question and then check my code ;)

Comment: Still needs an explanation.

Comment: multi: update multiple documents at once.
safe: verify that the update (write) was performed 

then you have the update query, "cn" is the field so you will update only that ones that the names will be equal to "req.params.name" value (In node you get query params like req.params). Then in the other part of the update you have to specify what you want to update. So basically the pull means that you will operate and remove a value over an array, the value is a subobject that have a property "favorites"

Comment: this favorites is an array of objects from other collection

Favorite {
...
favorites:[{
 _id: ObjectId("<id>")
}]
..

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample in TypeScript using Mongoose.

```
// Each company has COI
// COI looks like { buildingId: string, name: string, file: string }
// Company is an Entity Company looks like { companyId: string, cois: COI[] }

function deleteCOI(companyId: string, buildingId: string) {
  const company = await Companies.findOneAndUpdate(
    { companyId },
    { $pull: { cois: { buildingId: buildingId } } }
  );
  return company;
}
```