# How to remove array element in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Here is array structure

```
contact: {
    phone: [
        {
            number: "+1786543589455",
            place: "New Jersey",
            createdAt: ""
        }
        {
            number: "+1986543589455",
            place: "Houston",
            createdAt: ""
        }

    ]
}
```

Here I only know the mongo id(`_id`) and phone number(`+1786543589455`) and I need to remove that whole corresponding array element from document. i.e zero indexed element in phone array is matched with phone number and need to remove the corresponding array element.

```
contact: {
    phone: [
        {
            number: "+1986543589455",
            place: "Houston",
            createdAt: ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried with following update method

```
collection.update(
    { _id: id, 'contact.phone': '+1786543589455' },
    { $unset: { 'contact.phone.$.number': '+1786543589455'} }
);
```

But it removes  `number:  +1786543589455` from inner array object, not zero indexed element in phone array. Tried with `pull` also without a success.

How to remove the array element in mongodb?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
collection.update(
  { _id: id },
  { $pull: { 'contact.phone': { number: '+1786543589455' } } }
);
```

It will find document with the given `_id` and remove the phone `+1786543589455` from its `contact.phone` array.

You can use `$unset` to unset the value in the array (set it to `null`), but not to remove it completely.

Comment: Thank you. It works nice. I tried with `{ $pull: { 'contact.phone.$': { 'contact.phone.$.number': '+1786543589455' } } }` and `{ $pull: { 'contact.phone': { 'contact.phone.$.number': '+1786543589455' } } }` without a success.  Doesn't understand working of positional operators here?

Comment: Is there call back with this?

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns you could add a callback as a third argument, or you could use returned promise.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I tried this. In my case, I've multiple documents with same key. I want to $pull all these documents but current query only changes 1 document and then stops. What changes I need?

Comment: @ShubhamA. by default `.update()` updates a single document. To update multiple documents use `{ multi: true }` option. See [`db.collection.update` docs for details](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use $pull to remove a sub-document.
The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.

```
Collection.update({
    _id: parentDocumentId
  }, {
    $pull: {
      subDocument: {
        _id: SubDocumentId
      }
    }
  });
```

This will find your parent document against given ID and then will remove the element from subDocument which matched the given criteria.

Read more about pull [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull-array-of-documents).

Answer (score 6):

In Mongoose:
from the [document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-pull):

> To remove a document from a subdocument array we may pass an object
>   with a matching _id.

```
contact.phone.pull({ _id: itemId }) // remove
contact.phone.pull(itemId); // this also works
```

**See Leonid Beschastny's answer for the correct answer.**

Answer (score 4):

To remove all matching array elements from a specific document:

```
collection.update(
  { _id: id },
  { $pull: { 'contact.phone': { number: '+1786543589455' } } }
);
```

To remove all matching array elements from **all** documents:

```
collection.updateMany(
  { },
  { $pull: { 'contact.phone': { number: '+1786543589455' } } }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove all array elements irrespective of any given id, use this:

```
collection.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { 'contact.phone': { number: '+1786543589455' } } }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the following document in the profiles collection:

```
{ 
   _id: 1, 
   votes: [ 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8 ] 
}
```

The following operation will remove all items from the votes array that are greater than or equal to ($gte) 6:

```
db.profiles.update( { _id: 1 }, { $pull: { votes: { $gte: 6 } } } )
```

After the update operation, the document only has values less than 6:

```
{ 
   _id: 1, 
   votes: [  3,  5 ] 
}
```

If you have multiple items the with the same value, you should use $pullAll instead of $pull.

In the question having a multiple contact numbers the same use this:

```
collection.update(
  { _id: id },
  { $pullAll: { 'contact.phone': { number: '+1786543589455' } } }
);
```

It will delete every item that matches that number in contact phone.

Try reading the manual.

Comment: In the question having a fax number and a voice number the sameuse