# deleting route for an array in mongodB using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
 username:String,
 password:String,
 email:String,
 tasks:[{
   task: String
 }]
});
```

This is my database schema.I want to create a delete route for the task to be removed.Can anyone tell me how to do so. Right now I am able to fetch the task id.

Here is link to my c9 project https://ide.c9.io/akspan12/newprojectworkspace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove array element in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.patch("/todo/:id",function(req,res){
  User
    .findById(req.user.id, function(err, foundUser) {
        if(err){
            req.flash("error",err.message);
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect("back");
        } if(!foundUser) {
              req.flash("error","User not found");
            return res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            foundUser.update({$pull: {tasks: {_id: req.params.id}}}, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    req.flash("error",err.message);
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.redirect("back");
                } else {
                      req.flash("success","Task removed");
                    return res.redirect("/todo");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is the delete route I used.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express();

    //I will take static values you can give dynamic values by using req.body
    router.post('/Delete_User_Task',function(req,res){
        var UserSchema = require('/path/to/Schema.js');//your schema model path
        var username = 'akshansh123'; //assume it is present in db
        //If you want to remove all task of this user and set one task as empty string your query and changes will be like below
        var query = {
            'username' :username
        };
        var changes = {
            $set:{
                'tasks':[{
                    task:''
                }]
            }
        };

        //If you completely want to remove json array tasks from user document than your query and changes will be like below
        var query = {
            'username' :username
        };
        var changes = {
            $unset:{
                'tasks':''
            }
        };

        //If you want to remove particular task suppose say sleeping from user document than your query and changes will be like below
        var query = {
            'username' :username
        };
        var changes = {
            $pull:{
                'tasks':{
                    'task':'sleeping'
                }
            }
        };
    //If you want to remove selected tasks suppose say sleeping,walking,drinking from user document than your query and changes will be like below
        var query = {
            'username' :username
        };
        var changes = {
            $pull:{
                'tasks':{
                    'task':{
                        $in:['sleeping','walking','drinking']
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        UserSchema.update(query,changes,function(err,Result){
            if(!err){
                res.send('Successfully Removed tasks');
            }else{
                res.send('something went wrong');
                console.log(err);
            }
        })

    })
```

Hope this may solve your issue!!!

Comment: I found how to do it...but still thanks for reply..I used patch instead of post

Comment: you can post your answer and close this question