# Deleting a single item from a database with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a2de0a00d6baa43e8b925d0"
    },
    "name": "test",
    "playList": [
        {
            "url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/8aa799e60164f8a1fb311188d9d85ef65d7782c6?cid=ed36a056ee504173a3889b2e55cbd461",
            "artist": "Kenny G",
            "songName": "My Heart Will Go On (Love Theme from \"Titanic\")",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a2de0ad0d6baa43e8b925d1"
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/7c49854f18e6dfda6cd97ab5e8bc139d7ca82b7c?cid=ed36a056ee504173a3889b2e55cbd461",
            "artist": "PRODUCE 101",
            "songName": "PICK ME",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a2de13b0d6baa43e8b925d2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have a database called `channels` where each channels contain a `playList` as shown below. I want to delete a single item when a button is clicked. I can handle the onClick event part, but I am not sure how to implement the routes part.

I know that I start by doing something like

```
router.delete(''/channels/:id', function(req, res){

    something here...

})
```

but how can I access a particular item (probably with a unique id?) and delete it from the DB?

**EDIT**

By using the GET below

```
router.get('/channels/:id',
        isLoggedIn,
        function(req, res) {
            channel.findOne({'name':req.params.id},function(err,channeldata){
                if(err || channeldata === null){
                    res.status(404).send({
                        message: 'Channel Not Found',
                        data: []
                    })
                }
                else {
                    res.status(200).json({
                        message: "channel to "+req.params.id+"success",
                        data:channeldata
                    })
                }
            })
    });
```

I get the data for a single channel in my DB.

But since I am new to this stuff, I am not sure how to access each item of the `playList` and delete a single data.

**EDIT2**

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
var ChannelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String,required:true},
    playList: [{
        songName: { type : String },
        artist: { type : String },
        url: { type : String }
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Channel',ChannelSchema);
```

Comment: What are you using for your back-end?

Comment: tag `nodejs` too in your question

Comment: @oneturkmen nodejs sorry

Comment: Do you have the necessary `DELETE /channels/:id` endpoint? Or, you don't know how to create an endpoint at all? Sharing some code that you have already done (or at least tried to do) would be much more useful that just asking quite vague questions.

Comment: @oneturkmen I fixed my question. Could you please check?

Comment: @Dawn17 that's better! What is the definition of `channel`?

Comment: @oneturkmen are you talking about schema? I added it in my question

Comment: I mean the `channel.findOne(...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160893/discussion-between-oneturkmen-and-dawn17).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove array element in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following snippet that contains the `DELETE` (part of `CRUD`) endpoint for your resource collection (i.e. the `channels`):

```
router.delete('/channels/playlist/song', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {  

  const channel_id = req.query.channelId;
  const song_id    = req.query.songId;

  // the following query deletes a song form a playlist of a certain channel
  channel.update({_id: ObjectId(channel_id)},{$pull:{playList:{_id:ObjectId(song_id)}}})
    .exec()
    .then(result => {

      // for checking if document was found and deleted
      // mongodb actually returns special object `result`
      //   which has its own certain fields
      res.status(200).send({
        status: "success",
        message: result
      });   

    })
    .catch(error => {
        // here we see if we had any problem with server or db itself
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).send({
        success: false,
        message: "Something went wrong with DELETE /channels/:id"
      })
    })
});
```

I assume that you know what ObjectId() function does
if you do not have it declared, declare the following comment
in the beginning of the file (where you `require` everything)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // you must have this
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId; // gets the function
```

Let me know if this helps, or if you do not understand something - I will make an edit so that you get it.