# Remove items from Array which match at least one condition from a set of conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to execute a query which remove some specific elements which match at least one condition from a set of conditions,

```
{
    id: 'myId',
    path2: [{
        a: '1'
    },{
        a: '2'
    },{
        a: '3'
    }]
}
```

and update it to:

```
{
    id: 'myId',
    path2: [{
        a: '1'
    }]
}
```

Here, I removed from `path2` all elements where the value of the 'a' field is equal to either **2 or 3**.

I tried the following with no success (I'm using mongoose):

```
let conditions = ['2', '3'];

myModel.findOneAndUpdate({id: 'myId'},
    {$pull: {path2: {$elemMatch: {a: {$in: conditions}}}}}
);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `let conditions = ['2','3'];
myModel.findOneAndUpdate({id: 'myId'},
{$pull:{path2: {a: {$in:conditions}}}});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove array element in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb)

Comment: Thank you Veeram! it works nice :) . It's is not a duplicate question as i'm trying to find all values which fullfill a set of conditions and not only one condition as it is shown in the question you indicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do,

```
myModel.findOneAndUpdate({id: 'myId'}, {$pull: {path2: {a: {$in: conditions}}}} );
```

You don't need to use `elemMatch`.