# Pull 1 level deep array element from MongoDB document by indicating value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

How can I pull from the following MongoDB document all array elements from the groups array with the value `"abreiseValue":"25.02.2018",` so that there are no more array elements in the groups array with the value `"abreiseValue":"25.02.2018",`? I want to do it in NodeJS.

(In my real document I have more embedded documents in the groups array with the same structure)

```js
{  
   "_id":{  
      "$oid":"5a48d7c2f36d284acc10a64d"
   },
   "department":"edelweissKaminStube",
   "tables":[  
      {  
         "arrayIndex":0,
         "department":"edelweissKaminStube",
         "number":"80",
         "topValue":"345",
         "leftValue":"250",
         "bgColor":"#b7b7b7",
         "isBesetzt":"true",
         "placeholder":"true",
         "border":"solid 3px #f3efe4",
         "width":"40",
         "height":"35",
         "groups":[  
            {  
               "nameValue":"Prahst, Andreas",
               "zimmernummerValue":"705",
               "anreiseValue":"18.02.2018",
               "abreiseValue":"25.02.2018",
               "personenAnzahlValue":"2/0",
               "notiz2Value":"2*\u008030 Spa+TG",
               "notiz1Value":"2 Erw. neu",
               "traceValue":"-",
               "bemerkungValue":"Sie: Gluten und Milchunverträglichkeit "
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This is how I tried it, but it did not work. (Based on the following link: [how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb))

```js
db.hubertusTables.update({department: "edelweissKaminStube",
                         "tables.number": "80"},
                         {$pull: {"tables.$.groups": 
                         {abreiseValue: "25.02.2018"} } },
                         {multi: true});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
db.collectionName.findAndModify({
    query: {
        department: "edelweissKaminStube"
    },
    update: {
        $pull: { "tables.$[element].groups": { "abreiseValue": "25.02.2018" } }
    },
    arrayFilters: [ 
        { "element.number": "80" }
    ]
});
```

Details about this approach can be found on [$pull operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) and on [findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#findandmodify-arrayfilters) method.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get the following error: `{ MongoError: cannot use the part (tables of tables.$[element].groups) to traverse the element ({tables: [ { ...`

Comment: 3.6 is not available on mLab. Is there an alternative except leaving mLab? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Support for nested arrays update has been introduced from v3.5.12., as you can see at https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-831