# MongoDB find() in multidimensional array and $unset

Tags: php, mongodb

This is my Object on mongoDB, I need to find the **relations** objects in the array by ID and remove it object.

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b1a95c84700cb01758b4568"),
        "name" : "development",
        "type" : "",    
        "relations" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b1c290f20244eec02000029"),
                "name" : "mobile",
                "count" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b1c290f20244eec02000028"),
                "name" : "iOS",
                "count" : 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

What is the best way to find by relations object "_id" and then unset this object?

Here I am so getting ID

```
 $cursor = $collection->find([], ['relations' => []]);
 $find_id = "5b1c290f20244eec02000028";

        foreach (iterator_to_array($cursor) as $key) {
            foreach ($key['relations'] as $key2) {
                if ((string)$key2['_id'] == $find_id) {
                    var_dump($key2['_id']);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: See also [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) in the documentation. It's basically the top hit on a google search https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+remove+from+array

Comment: Thanks dear  :) I did a poor search..

Comment: but it didn't work.. Where am I wrong?
`$collection->update(
            [],
            ['$pull' => ['relations' => ["_id" => new MongoId('5b1c290f20244eec02000028')] ]],
            ["multi" => true]
        );`

Comment: You appear to be reading old documentation. `new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId` is where the `ObjectId` method resides in modern drivers.

Comment: I tried in many ways.. even I copied from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb) which you indicated (db and answer) tried but does not work.. `$set` and `$unset` working but `$pull` does not work at all... my mongodb version is `v3.4.7` and I work in the local

Comment: Please think for a moment Hundreds of Thousands if not millions of people use this all the time `db.collection.update({}, { "$pull": { "relations": { "_id": ObjectId("5b1c290f20244eec02000028") } } })` works just fine and removes the element from your document as listed in the question. Read the documentation, use the shell to practice from samples there and then look at your code and apply the correct options. You need the correct `ObjectId` type in order to match an `ObjectId`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much ))