# $pull operator in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pull

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5badfada90fd543fd8aa7f96"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "deleted" : false,
    "groups" : [ 
        {
            "group" : "grp",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bae09a601123357e58b66a2"),
            "activities" : [ 
                ObjectId("5bae09a601123357e58b66a3"), 
                ObjectId("5bae10de01123357e58b66a6")
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "group" : "123",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bae0f1001123357e58b66a4"),
            "activities" : [ 
                ObjectId("5bae0f1001123357e58b66a5")
            ]
        }
    ],
    "nextActivityId" : 22,
    "name" : "test",
    "year" : "1",
    "status" : "2",
    "vision" : ObjectId("5bab2f4872acf42a81c124d0")
}
```

The Above Schema is a "Plan" Schema
I have to write a query for removing an Activity inside "activities" array. What will be the optimum solution for this? And how will I use $pull to achieve this
This was my solution, but it will delete the complete groups array

```
Plan.update({ _id: PLAN ID }, { $pull: { groups: { activities: ACTIVITY ID } } })
```

PLAN ID BEING: "_id" : ObjectId("5badfada90fd543fd8aa7f96"),
ACTIVITY ID FOR EXAMPLE BEING: ObjectId("5bae09a601123357e58b66a3")

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove array element in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the positional `$` update operator.

```
db.Plan.update(
    { "_id" : PLAN ID }, 
    { "$pull": { "groups.$.activities": ACTIVITY ID } } 
)
```

Comment: @AkhileshOjha: If this answer accomplishes your aim please accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
    db.Plan.update({ _id: ObjectId("5badfada90fd543fd8aa7f96"),"groups.activities":{$in:[ ObjectId("5bae09a601123357e58b66a3") ]}},
{ $pull: { "groups.$.activities": ObjectId("5bae09a601123357e58b66a3") }  });
```

The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query warning when use `$` only update object.