# How to remove an object in array in mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Please I am new in mongo db and I want to delete one item from my list, I tried several approches but it's not working.

```
{

name: 'ABCDE',

snapshotString: [
        '{"timestamp":1589316266621,"testObject":{}, "moreAttributes" : "XXXXX"}',
        '{"timestamp":1589316279337,"testObject":{}, "moreAttributes" : "XXXXX"}'
],
snapshots: [
   1589316266621,
    1589316279337
]
}
```

I want to delete a `snapshotString` for given timestamp I did this:

```
this.testCase.updateOne(
                {name:room, "snapshotString.timestamp": timestamp}, 
                { $pull: { "snapshotString.timestamp": timestamp } }, { safe: true }, 
                function(err, obj) {
                    console.log(" ***** err ***** "+err);
        });
```

And it's a way to have one query to delete both documents with timestamp in `snapshotString` and `snapshots` in the same query?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb

Comment: In that example `snapshotString` contains an array of strings, not an array of objects.  Strings don't have fields, so you can't query `snapshotString.timestamp` - it will never match anything.  You might try a regular expression for that match.

Comment: @whoami unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below:

```
this.testCase.updateOne(
    {name: room},
    {$pull:
        {snapshotString:
            {$regex: timestamp}
        }
    });
```

**Note:** I am assuming here, `timestamp` is a string, if not, then you should convert it to string, as `$regex` operator will accept only string.