# How to modify mongo references?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these models

```
var NotesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: String, 
    category: [{ type: mongoose.ObjectId, ref: "Categories", default: [] }], 
  }
);
var CategoriesSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }, 
  notes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Notes' }]
});
var Notes = mongoose.model("Notes", NotesSchema);
var Cat = mongoose.model("Categories", CategoriesSchema);
```

I created the ability to add a note and the database get's populated. I post something like this

```
{ "title": "Post two", "categories": [ "tagOne", "tagTwo"  ] }
```

And the dummy final result in the DB is:

```
/* Notes Collection */
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7bd0ee7e59d9265a869427"),
    "category" : [ 
        ObjectId("5f7bd0ee7e59d9265a869428") //tagOne
    ],
    "title" : "Post One",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7bd0fc7e59d9265a869429"),
    "category" : [ 
        ObjectId("5f7bd0ee7e59d9265a869428"), tagOne
        ObjectId("5f7bd0fc7e59d9265a86942a")  //tagTwo
    ],
    "title" : "Post two",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

And the Categories Collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7bd0ee7e59d9265a869428"),
    "notes" : [ 
        ObjectId("5f7bd0ee7e59d9265a869427"), 
        ObjectId("5f7bd0fc7e59d9265a869429")
    ],
    "name" : "tagOne",
    "__v" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7bd0fc7e59d9265a86942a"),
    "notes" : [ 
        ObjectId("5f7bd0fc7e59d9265a869429")
    ],
    "name" : "tagTwo",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Say I want to remove `tagOne` from `Post two`. I can easily find `Post two` and remove the id of `tagOne` from the array list. But at the same time I'd need to go to `tagOne` and remove the id of `Post two`.

Above I have `Post two`, it has two categories, If I want to remove one how the tags from the post, how to I remove it from the note and remove the note from category

Action: remove "category1" from "post one", AND "post one" from "category1"

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @D.SM how to modify the reference wherever they appear.

Comment: @D.SM I added a bit of clarification on the bottom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove array element in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb)