# Delete an income record inside an array object of a user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

MongoDB user entry

[image]

Controllers code:

[image]

```
                module.exports.deleteIncome = (params) => {
                    return User.findById(params.userId) // I went to the user here
                    .then((user, err) => {
                        if(err) return false
                        user.incomeRecords.remove( "_id": "{params.incomeRecordId}" ) // my delete income record syntax
                        return user.save()
                        .then((updateUser, err) => {
                            return(err) ? false : true
                        })
                    })
                }
```

Here's my code, it's not working
Please see the pic i provided
I want to delete the specific income record inside the user's array incomeRecords
Please help thanks =)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove array element in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mongodb pull operator. It would look something like this:-

```js
findOneAndUpdate({userid:params.userid},{
  $pull:{
      incomeRecords:{
         _id:<the mongodb id here>
      }
  }
})
```

Check out the mongodb [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/index.html)