# How to delete an object from an array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

**How to delete or remove any object inside mainlist array**

```
 _id:ObjectId("5fafc5aec2b84c301845c55a"),
    username:"test",
       mainList:[
           {
             _id:ObjectId("5fafdf1a5b49510c789af0ae"),
             name:"testname",
             lastname:"testlastname"
           },
           {
            _id:ObjectId("5fafdf1a5b49510c789af0af"),
            name:"testname",
            lastname:"testlastname"
            }
         ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove array element in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$pull` operator

```js
{ $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition>, <field2>: <value|condition>, ... } }
```