# Mongo remove document if all elements in array match condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Docs:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  items: [{thing: 5}, {thing: 7}]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  items: [{thing: 5}, {thing: 11}]
}
```

I would like to remove all docs from the collection above if all elements in array have "thing" < 10.  IE for that case doc 1 should be removed, doc 2 should remain.

Is it possible with a query to find only docs where all elements in the array match with a $lt query?

I tried this:

```
db.mycollection.remove({items: {$all: [{$elemMatch: {thing: {$lt: 11}}}]}})
```

However that will remove all docs if any of the elements in the array match the condition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb

Comment: @AlokDeshwal not the same question.  I want to remove the entire document if all elements in array match, not just pull matching elements from document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double negative (De-Morgan law):

```mongodb
{items: {$not: {$elemMatch: {thing: {$gte: 11}}}}}
```