# How do I remove/delete project from project array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to delete a project object from an array.

**projects**:

```
  {
      _id : ...,
      userName: milad ,
      projets : [
        { .. projectId, pName, location .... A },
        { .. projectId, pName, location .... B },
        { .. projectId, pName, location .... C },
      ]
    }
```

How to delete Project B in MongoDB?

**projects after remove Project B**:

```
{
  _id : ...,
  userName: milad ,
  projets : [
    { .. projectId, pName, location .... A },
    { .. projectId, pName, location .... C },
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: maybe [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have received a document from your database, you can remove an object from your array - based on the location - in such a way:

```
const doc = {
  _id: '507f191e810c19729de860e0',
  userName: 'milad',
  projects: [
    { _id: '507f191e810c19729de860ea', pName: 'projectA', location: 'a' },
    { _id: '507f191e810c19729de860eb', pName: 'projectB', location: 'b' },
    { _id: '507f191e810c19729de860ec', pName: 'projectC', location: 'c' }
  ]
}

// remove project b (one method, there are many more)
doc.projects = doc.projects.filter((project) => project.location !== 'b');
```

After the filter process you have to save it back to your mongoDB:

**Mongoose: (example)**

```
await doc.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

another answer

```
db.collection('Profile').updateOne({ userName: username,
      "Projects.projectId": projectId }, { $pull: { 'Projects': { projectId: projectId } }})
  }
```