# Mongoose how to update array from child to parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have following schema for Audio.

```
const AudioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    uploaderId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Instead of referencing the User, I just store the User's `_id` as uploaderId.

In my User schema I also have `audioFiles: [Audio]` array for all audio files that user has uploaded.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...,
    audioFiles: [Audio]
});
```

When I try to update my AudioSchema from my REST Api, I can change all the properties and that works, but after saving this Audio model those changes doesn't affect the User model.

Now I created a new branch and try to change `uploaderId` to `UserSchema`. But I wonder is there a solution for this without referencing the `UserSchema`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with help of `MongooseArray.prototype.pull` method.

Steps for solving this problem is really easy.

First I get the User that is associated with AudioModel.uploaderId, then I used the `user.audioFiles.pull()` method. Correct code is below.

```
let user = await UserService.getUser(userId);

await user.audioFiles.pull({
    _id: audioId //audioId is the id which i'm trying to remove from array
});

await user.save();
```

I also added try-catch block to handle errors.

Anyone having this kind of issue can use the link below to get more information about [`MongooseArray.prototype.pull`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-pull) method.

Also you can check the other answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763721/mongoose-delete-array-element-in-document-and-save) post.