# NodeJs Mongoose - remove one id from array in document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array in my model document. I would like to remove one id in that array. Is this possible?

[image: document with array of object id's]

This is what I tried.

```
module.exports.RemoveFavourite = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.params.user;
    const favouriteId = req.params.event;

    const removeFavourite = await User.updateOne(
      { _id: userId },
      { $pull: { favourites: favouriteId } }
    );

    res.status(200).json(removeFavourite);
  } catch {
    res.status('404').json('error');
  }
};
```

Comment: i think same here. [mongoose-delete-array-element-in-document-and-save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763721/mongoose-delete-array-element-in-document-and-save)

Comment: The query [looks good](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0hjOTiYaRW1) so maybe you have to parse `favouriteId` to `ObjectId`. By the way you can try to do a `find` query to ensure data is ok. If aquery [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MjFv68X3v2y) works properly, the update should too.

Answer (score 1):

convert favouriteId `string to ObjectId`

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

module.exports.RemoveFavourite = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.params.user;
    const favouriteId = req.params.event;

    const removeFavourite = await User.updateOne(
      { _id: userId },
      { $pull: { favourites: mongoose.Type.ObjectId(favouriteId) } }
    );

    res.status(200).json(removeFavourite);
  } catch {
    res.status('404').json('error');
  }
};
```